# 2nd Level .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used to have two .htaccess files in my projet, We have the following directories.

```
 MainProject/
      .htaccess        //first .htaccess
      public/
         .htaccess     //second .htaccess
```

The projects used to work fine, but once I've uninstalled and installed apache, everything changed.

This is .htaccess 1 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

And, this is .htaccess 2 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I activated the mod_rewrite module.

If I write in the address bar :

> http://myproject.lan/

It takes me to the home page, meaning that .htaccess 1 is working just fine.

But when I write something like :

> http://myproject.lan/login

It doesn't work, and it shows a "page not found" message.

What happens when project works, is that /login = $1 , so, it looks for public/login (in .htaccess 1)

Then, in public directory, the server executes the second .htaccess, where $1 matched to /index.php?url=/login, which is eventually sent to the front controller, waiting to be processed and converted to an existing route.

If there's something I need to enable on Apache, let me know because I forgot how I managed to make it work before in the first place.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess 1 is just fine? It sounds like its just hitting the index page. Make sure you have changed "AllowOverride" to `All` in your apache config/vhost file. So that it will make sure to read the htaccess files.

Comment: Thank you, I already added AllowOverride All, and htaccess 1 is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem, The problem is that in my

> httpd-vhosts.conf

I forgot to add `/public` to the DocumentRoot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `/public/.htaccess` should be like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem is presence of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/* [NC]` condition in this .htaccess

Comment: Maybe it can be a problem on other cases, but for me it's not the problem... I just found the solution, and posted it

Comment: Actually if `/public` is  `DocumentRoot` then 1) first .htaccess won't even matter. You can even delete it. 2) `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/* [NC]` is also useless since it will always return true

Comment: Yes this is what I did, I figured out that the first htaccess is there for a previous configuration... sometimes, we point documentRoot to the main directory (not the /public directory).

But, I think, we're gonna remove it as you said, and make it point to /public. Thank you :D